# Jest react ionic app - @ionic/storage module not found

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, npm, jestjs

I am using Jest to create test for a ionic react app.

The app was created with create react app.

I created a basic test for Login component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Login from './Login';

test('renders without crashing', () => {
  const { baseElement } = render(<Login />);
  expect(baseElement).toBeDefined();
});
```

In the login component I have the import:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

I am able to use `Storage` to work with storage but when I run the test above I got the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

Cannot find module '@ionic/storage' from 'src/pages/Login.tsx'
```

I am using docker and the module is present inside `node_modules/@ionic/storage`.

I googled a lot but I didn't find a solution so far.

Comment: Any update on this? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: not yet, unfortunately. I guess that is a problem with the npm package

Comment: Tried downgrading to 2.x but that one only has angular support :(

Comment: Do u have `storage` folder inside `@ionic` in `node_modules`?

Comment: Yeah I do have that folder as you can see here: https://imgur.com/KdPeXW9, you don't see it on your side?

Comment: I am using docker and I have the module inside the container

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find the proper way of doing this but a work around I have is this:

in the src folder create a __mocks__ folder. inside create a @ionic folder and then two files: storage.d.ts and storage.ts the files are:

storage.d.ts

```js
/** @hidden */
export declare const Drivers: {
  SecureStorage: string;
  IndexedDB: string;
  LocalStorage: string;
};

export interface StorageConfig {
  name?: string;
  version?: number;
  size?: number;
  storeName?: string;
  description?: string;
  driverOrder?: Driver[];
  dbKey?: string;
}

export declare type Database = any;

declare type Driver = any;

export declare class Storage {
  private _config;

  private _db;

  private _secureStorageDriver;

  /**
   * Create a new Storage instance using the order of drivers and any additional config
   * options to pass to LocalForage.
   *
   * Possible default driverOrder options are: ['indexeddb', 'localstorage'] and the
   * default is that exact ordering.
   *
   * When using Ionic Secure Storage (enterprise only), use ['ionicSecureStorage', 'indexeddb', 'localstorage'] to ensure
   * Secure Storage is used when available, or fall back to IndexedDB or LocalStorage on the web.
   */
  constructor(config?: StorageConfig);

  create(): Promise<Storage>;

  /**
   * Define a new Driver. Must be called before
   * initializing the database. Example:
   *
   * await storage.defineDriver(myDriver);
   * await storage.create();
   */
  defineDriver(driver: Driver): Promise<void>;

  /**
   * Get the name of the driver being used.
   * @returns Name of the driver
   */
  get driver(): string | null;

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/member-ordering
  private readonly assertDb;

  /**
   * Get the value associated with the given key.
   * @param key the key to identify this value
   * @returns Returns a promise with the value of the given key
   */
  get(key: string): Promise<any>;

  /**
   * Set the value for the given key.
   * @param key the key to identify this value
   * @param value the value for this key
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves when the key and value are set
   */
  set(key: string, value: any): Promise<any>;

  /**
   * Remove any value associated with this key.
   * @param key the key to identify this value
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves when the value is removed
   */
  remove(key: string): Promise<any>;

  /**
   * Clear the entire key value store. WARNING: HOT!
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves when the store is cleared
   */
  clear(): Promise<void>;

  /**
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves with the number of keys stored.
   */
  length(): Promise<number>;

  /**
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves with the keys in the store.
   */
  keys(): Promise<string[]>;

  /**
   * Iterate through each key,value pair.
   * @param iteratorCallback a callback of the form (value, key, iterationNumber)
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves when the iteration has finished.
   */
  forEach(
    iteratorCallback: (value: any, key: string, iterationNumber: Number) => any
  ): Promise<void>;

  setEncryptionKey(key: string): void;
}
export {};
```

storage.ts

```js
import LocalForage from "localforage";
/** @hidden */
export const Drivers = {
  SecureStorage: "ionicSecureStorage",
  IndexedDB: LocalForage.INDEXEDDB,
  LocalStorage: LocalForage.LOCALSTORAGE,
};
const defaultConfig = {
  name: "_ionicstorage",
  storeName: "_ionickv",
  dbKey: "_ionickey",
  driverOrder: [Drivers.SecureStorage, Drivers.IndexedDB, Drivers.LocalStorage],
};
export class Storage {
  /**
   * Create a new Storage instance using the order of drivers and any additional config
   * options to pass to LocalForage.
   *
   * Possible default driverOrder options are: ['indexeddb', 'localstorage'] and the
   * default is that exact ordering.
   *
   * When using Ionic Secure Storage (enterprise only), use ['ionicSecureStorage', 'indexeddb', 'localstorage'] to ensure
   * Secure Storage is used when available, or fall back to IndexedDB or LocalStorage on the web.
   */
  constructor(config = defaultConfig) {}

  async create() {}

  /**
   * Get the value associated with the given key.
   * @param key the key to identify this value
   * @returns Returns a promise with the value of the given key
   */
  get(key: any) {}

  /**
   * Set the value for the given key.
   * @param key the key to identify this value
   * @param value the value for this key
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves when the key and value are set
   */
  set(key: any, value: any) {}

  /**
   * Remove any value associated with this key.
   * @param key the key to identify this value
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves when the value is removed
   */
  remove(key: any) {}

  /**
   * Clear the entire key value store. WARNING: HOT!
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves when the store is cleared
   */
  clear() {}

  /**
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves with the number of keys stored.
   */
  length() {}

  /**
   * @returns Returns a promise that resolves with the keys in the store.
   */
  keys() {}
}
```

This lets my tests run and I can enter mock data I need.

I know this isn't perfect or fully correct but it lets me continue to run my project other tests

Answer (score 0):

In the [capacitor documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/mocking-plugins#manual-mocks) it says you have to create a folder in the project root, ok. Since, as I believe you are using Typescript, if you define a `baseUrl`, it will resolve all files from the folder set there, as stated in the [baseUrl documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl). The most common case is to set the `baseUrl: 'src'`, maybe that's because when you put it in `src` it worked.